# Почему LWRP дублирует свет на overlay камеры? Unity 2D Light

Tags: unity3d

Для эффекта параллакс я использовал несколько камер. Они имеют разный размер. При добавлении света, свет — дублируется на все камеры, и один и тот же свет видно два, три раза. Эффект заметен только тогда, когда камера имеет отличающийся от стальных камер размер. Прикрепляю сцену-пример, на которой проверял почему же происходит дубль. В Culling Mask, конечно же, light не стоит. Но он все равно рендерится. Как исправить дубликат света на overlay камерах?[image: 3 камеры - 2 оверлей - 1 камера base]

[image: 1 камера оверлей, 1 камера base. 2 камеры одинакового размера][image: свет]

Comment: Интересно, что в документации к версии 7.3.1 есть пометка `Important note: In this version of URP, Camera Stacking is not supported when using the 2D Renderer or when using the VR Multi Pass mode. Support for these will be added in upcoming versions of URP.` и stacking не работает действительно, в 7.4.1 пометки нет, stacking работает с такими артефактами, а в версии 8.0 снова есть пометка. Так что, видимо, это что-то сырое. В 8.2 пометки нет, а в 9 снова есть. Попробуйте 8.2, благо 2020.1 вчера вышла из беты. UPD: можете не пробовать, там та же проблема

Comment: @luvjungle О, спасибо за свежую информацию по релизам. Попробую.